# Two p tag in same line

Tags: html, css

I have two `p` tags

```
<p style="margin: 0; display: inline;">content1</p>
<p style="margin: 0; display: inline;" align="right">content2</p>
```

The Output is `content1content2`. My expectation is like this:

```
content1                                                                content2
```

Can anyone help. I want one "content1" in the left `p` and "content2" in the right 'p'.

Comment: content1 should be in extreme left and content2 should be in extreme right.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use [CSS flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) for this. Below is the minimal CSS for the requested layout:

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
  <p style="background-color: papayawhip;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p style="background-color: palegoldenrod;">Donec eget luctus lacus.</p>
</div>
```

For longer content, you can use fixed-width columns:

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
  <p style="flex-basis: 49.5%; background-color: papayawhip;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget luctus lacus. Cras consectetur elementum mi sed consequat.</p>
  <p style="flex-basis: 49.5%; background-color: palegoldenrod;">Pellentesque aliquet condimentum augue in mattis. Praesent sagittis nisl magna, a volutpat arcu imperdiet vel. Quisque et orci sed ligula cursus luctus.</p>
  <!-- 49.5% + 49.5% = 99%, remaining 1% is distributed according to justify-content -->
</div>
```

Comment: how would I display the second <p> right after the first one and not at the right end of the page

Answer (score 8):

You could do it with floats:

```
<p style="margin:0;display:inline;float:left">content1</p>
<p style="margin:0;display:inline:float:right" >content2</p>
```

Answer (score 5):

The idea of the tag `<p></p>` is to display a paragraph. So HTML offers you the `<div></div>` which is a container conecpt. So you should use Salman A's Solution, because there aren't just different tags in html for no reason. Actually you can style a paragraph with css so it is getting displayed the same as a div container, but it is not meant to be like that.
I don't want to say to you, what you have to do. I just wanna help you using the "correct" tags for the things they were made for.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is something that doesn't assume sufficent width to fit both paragraphs into one line:

[image: Two paragraphs, side-by-side, with one of them occupying two lines]

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.two { width: 30em; max-width: 100%; }
.two p { display: inline-block; max-width: 50%; }
.two p:nth-child(1) { float:left; }
.two p:nth-child(2) { float:right; }
```

```html
<div class="two">
    <p>This is the first paragraph of two.</p>
    <p>This is the second paragraph of two.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another quick turnaround to achieve this:

```css
p{
  text-align: center;
}
.item p{
  display: inline-block;
}
.leftContent{
  text-align: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.rightContent{
  text-align: right;
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<br>
<!--Use both P tags in the same line without space -->
<article class="item">
  <p class="leftContent">Content1</p><p class="rightContent">Content2</p>
</article>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

`float:left`, `float:right`.... or

```
width:49.9%;
display:inline;
text-align:left;
text-align:right;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Got it! i will be more detail the next time, thanks Donald