# How can I float text to the right, while keeping it inline with the div it is inside of?

Tags: html, css

I would like to keep two `<p>` elements inline after I float one of them to the right.

```css
.bottomtext {
  background-color: #e6fbd0;
}

.bottomtext p {
  display: inline;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottomtext">
  <p class="right">
    © Name
  </p>
  <p>
    <a>Text</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

The problem is so simple that I don't know why it even exists without an obvious fix.
Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/of73hrd5/). This is the first website I have ever made, so bear with me...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two p tag in same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310736/two-p-tag-in-same-line)

Comment: The space is being created because your browser default p margin applies to your floated element (but not your inline element) either remove the margin or make the p inline-block so the margin is applied to both.  But in the age of css3, you should not be abusing floats to position elements like this - use something like flex instead

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin: *The top and bottom margins have no effect on non-replaced inline elements*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can float the text left, the name right:

```css
.bottomtext {
  background-color: #e6fbd0;
  overflow:auto;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottomtext">
  <p class="right">
    © Name
  </p>
  <p class="left">
    <a>Text</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Or maybe use flexbox:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #e6fbd0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>@ Name</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do should be easier with [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Maybe something like this:

```
.bottomtext {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Note that the `flex-direction: row` is the default direction when using `display: flex`.